# Cannot get backlight controls to work for an external monitor on a NUC on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, intel-graphics, backlight, intel-nuc

I am trying to set up backlight controls, but cannot find a way to make it work.

By default I have `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0`, but that does not respond to my brightness settings.

Knowing that I'm on a Intel NUC, obviously there are Intel Graphics installed:

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Iris Plus Graphics 655
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:bf000000-bfffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

And that makes me think that instead of `acpi_video0`, I should have a `intel_backlight` option.

I have tried to use kernel parameters:

- `acpi_backlight=vendor` - does not help, removed the `acpi_video0`, but didn't provide anything in place.
- `video.use_native_backlight=0` - `Jun 05 16:35:41 busmatic13 kernel: video: unknown parameter 'use_native_backlight' ignored`
- same with `video.use_native_backlight=1`

Tried to install `xserver-xorg-video-intel` - didn't help.

At first I tried to work with the native `xbacklight` utility, but that errored out: `No outputs have backlight property`.
Then I set up [`acpilight`](https://gitlab.com/wavexx/acpilight), while it did change values, it didn't update anything on the actual display.

**UPDATE**: This is to control an external monitor!

Answer (score 1):

External monitors lack hardware brightness control through the cable. You can use the controls on the monitor or through software:

```
xrandr --output MONITOR_NAME --brightness .85
```

This will give 85% brightness. To get MONITOR_NAME use:

```
xrandr | grep " connected"
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ddcutil`](https://github.com/rockowitz/ddcutil) does the magic:

```
ddcutil setvcp 10 <brightness as percentage (0-100)>
               ^^
               is the feature name for brightness, returned by `ddcutil capabilities`
```

Comment: And the rubber duck debugging strikes again! Immediately after posting, one last Google search prompted me to see what this `ddcutil` is all about and would that work. Jeez!